# How to embed mp4 video in FireFox without .ogg or .webm

Tags: html, firefox, video, mp4, instagram

I'm working on an application which utilizes Instagrams real-time api. Basically my app loops through any uploaded Instagram videos with a specific Hashtag. That part is working fantastic.

Here's where I have a problem, Instagram only provide their videos as .mp4 which doesn't work in all versions of Firefox <21. After a fair bit of investigation on the Mozilla blog it appears that mp4 isn't supported due to patenting issues, and it looks like it's going to stay that way.

Just to make it clear that re-saving/encoding the videos as .ogg/webm isn't practical as I'm purely relying on Instagram hosting the videos and then providing the source url to the video.

So I require a fallback. Can a flash player be used to play mp4 videos? I tend to steer well clear of Flash so I'm very unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Yes, you could provide a fallback in flash for the unsupported format, within the `sources` of the `html5` element `video`.

Comment: So using the mp4 as the source, within a flash embedded object? can you provide an example?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/use-html-5-video-on-all-browsers/

Comment: I was actually reading this article last night and tried that mp4->flash generator tool but it didn't appear to work. here's where I am at the moment, works fine in Firefox (Windows 7), but didn't in FireFox OSX [http://dev.projectmayhem.co.uk/](http://dev.projectmayhem.co.uk/)

Comment: Maybe this one then: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/video-for-everybody-html5-video-with-flash-fallback/

Comment: Looks straight forward enough, excuse my ignorance, but do I still need to host the flash_palyer.swf file? I'm guessing this is the flash plugin/player that actually plays the mp4

Comment: Yes, you would need to have the flash player files hosted in your end.

Comment: Just to update -

video.js seems to fallback quite gracefully to a Flash player. The API documentation seems a bit sparse but my first test worked fine

http://www.videojs.com/